# Volley error: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of , code: null

Tags: android, android-volley

This my response of JSON DATA:

```
{
    "markers": [
        {
            "error": false,
            "title": "name",
            "lat": "17.415751",
            "lng": "78.443277",
            "video": "vlc-record-2020-02-14-16h29m53s-GlintandGlowJewellerypresentation.mp4",
            "image": "51457.jpg",
            "address": "Hyderabad,
            "phone": "4023384555",
            "name": "name"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my first time making an android application that parses JSON data. However, I'm encountering an error regarding JSON parsing. I've tried Googling the problem but most of the solutions didn't work for me.

My request looks something like this:

RequestQueue req = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;


    JsonObjectRequest strReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        //http://justasec.in/JustASec/jas.php
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

            try {


                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                JSONArray commentsObj = obj.getJSONArray("markers");

                for (int i = 0; i < commentsObj.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject commentObj = (JSONObject) commentsObj.get(i);
                    String title = commentObj.getString("title");
                    String address = commentObj.getString("address");
                    String phone = commentObj.getString("phone");

                    // String contact_person = commentObj.getString("contact_person");
                    lat = commentObj.getString("lat");
                    lng = commentObj.getString("lng");
                    /*Image = "http://amazearapp.com/jvdweb/images/medium/"+ commentObj.getString("images");

                    VIDEO_SAMPLE ="http://amazearapp.com/jvdweb/videos/" + commentObj.getString("video");
                    initializePlayer();
```

*/
                        mapView.getMapAsync(DataActivity.this);

```
                    Title.setText(title);
                    //Address.setText(address);
                  /*  if (contact_person != null && !contact_person.isEmpty()) {
                        ContactPerson.setText(contact_person);
                    } else {
                        ContactPerson.setText("NA");
                        ContactPerson.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }*/


                    if (phone != null && !phone.isEmpty()) {
                        Number = phone;
                    } else {
                        Number = "NA";
                        call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    sliderImg = new ArrayList<>();


                    DiscountModel model = new DiscountModel();
                    model.setName("Image");
                    model.setImage(commentObj.getString("image"));
                    sliderImg.add(model);



                    if (commentObj.getString("video") != null) {
                        DiscountModel model1 = new DiscountModel();
                        model1.setName("Video");
                        model1.setImage(commentObj.getString("video"));
                        sliderImg.add(model1);
                    }

                    Log.v("size", sliderImg.size() + " ");

                    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(sliderImg,DataActivity.this);
                    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
```

Comment: Are you sure you receive data?

Comment: Before i get the data.. after i will change the Url Http to Https from that i am not receiving any data and irs showing the volley parsing error..

Comment: json parsing error: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: you are facing this error because you are probably not receiving any data so json is empty